# Database driver error CMN1022 loading data From AS400 to SQL with Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

Any ideas how to solve this, when I try to run workflow but hitting below message.

```
Message Code: CMN_1022
Message: Database driver error...
CMN_1022 [Database driver event...Error occurred loading library [pmdb2.dll]. System error encountered is 126. Error text is The specified module could not be found.
.]
```

My environment is as follows:

- Target: Windows Server 2012
- Informatica PowerCenter 9.1.0
- Source : AS400 - Cobol
- Powercenter repository is on SQL Server 2012.

And for As400 my Relational Connection setup, should I set up as DB2 or ODBC?
Did I need to config any ODBC.INI or HOSTS file(system file).

Comment: Just at a glance it looks like you'd be missing the DB2 connector on the Integration Service. You'd need to contact the Informatica Administrators in your company.

Comment: Maciejg - We don't have Informatica Administrator, that why we need help on this.

Comment: Please refer to "PowerCenter Installation and Configuration Guide" section  "Connecting to an IBM DB2 Universal Database" in the appendix. There are a few steps required to connect to DB2 discussed.